# how to check input type image value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the value of input type = image instead of input type = checkbox

This is the template

```
<div class="wrap_col td5"><input type="image" src="/pc/images/kick.png" alt="Submit" id="buttonKick" value="{$participant.channel}"></div>
```

This is the function

```
$('#buttonKick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
    var data = [];
    var conference = $("select[name='subuid'] option:selected").val();
    var action = "confbridgekick";
    getAllCheckAtParticipants(conference,data, action ,function(results){
        socket.emit("action",results);
    });
```

this is the action

```
var getAllCheckAtParticipants = function(conference, data, action, callback) {
    var $chk = $("#room_"+conference).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not(".chkAllParticipants");
    $chk.each(function(index){
        if (action=="confbridgekick") {
            var channel = $(this).val();
            data.push({ 'action': action, 'conference': conference, 'channel': channel });
        }
    });
```

How can i change this to check the value of input type = image

```
    var $chk = $("#room_"+conference).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").not(".chkAllParticipants");
```

Comment: What's the problem, what's not working? More information required...

Comment: i edited @Jamie . . thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[type='image']").val();
```